# XSL-FO - add a background image to multiple PDF pages

Tags: xml, xslt, background, xsl-fo, apache-fop

i'm generating a pdf using a XML and a XSL via Apache FOP, java Library.

I can't figure out how to display a background image for each page (or even a single page...).

The back ground needs to placed at the bottom of the text and to cover almost all the page (margins excluded).

I've searched with no good result, thank you in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="fo"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<xsl:template match="TbOnoriCaricaVO">
<xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>
<xsl:variable name="lowercase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>

<fo:root>
      <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="template" 
                                             page-height="297mm" page-width="210mm" margin- 
top="33mm" 
                                             margin-bottom="36mm" margin-left="22mm" margin- 
right="25mm"> 
            <fo:region-body>
                <fo:block width="15mm" height="25mm">
                    <fo:external-graphic  src="file:///D:/LungaNavigazioneAerea.png" />
                </fo:block> 
            </fo:region-body>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
      </fo:layout-master-set>

    <xsl:for-each select="TbOnoriCaricaVORow"> 

        <!--
        <fo:block-container absolute-position="absolute"
            top="-20mm" left="-30mm" width="15mm" height="25mm"
            background-image="file:///D:/LungaNavigazioneAerea.png">-->

          <xsl:variable name="medal">
             <xsl:value-of select="OnoriDesOnor"/>
          </xsl:variable>
          <fo:page-sequence master-reference="template">

            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">


              <fo:block-container  absolute-position="absolute"
                top="-20mm" left="-30mm" width="15mm" height="25mm"
                background-image="D:/LungaNavigazioneAerea.png">
                <fo:block/>
             </fo:block-container> 

              <fo:block font-family="Times New Roman" font-size="13pt" margin-top="0.43cm" margin- 
  left="1.7cm">
                <fo:inline>
                  <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(concat(&quot;Numero d&apos;ordine: &quot;, 
      &quot;~~~~~/&quot;, OnoriFfaa))"/> 
                </fo:inline>
              </fo:block>


            <fo:block text-align="center" margin-top="1.04cm">
              <fo:inline font-family="Times New Roman" font-size="19pt">
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
              </fo:inline>
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block text-align="center" font-family="Times New Roman" font-size="13pt" margin- 
    top="-0.04cm">
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block text-align="center" font-family="Times New Roman" font-size="13pt" margin- 
    top="0.14cm">
              ~~~~~~~~
            </fo:block>


            <fo:block text-align="left" font-family="Times New Roman" font-size="12pt" margin- 
   top="5.31cm" margin-left="1.7cm">
              <fo:inline>
                  <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(concat('Al ~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~ ', OnoriNome, 
       ' ', OnoriCognome))"/> 
              </fo:inline>
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block text-align="left" font-family="Times New Roman" font-size="12pt" margin- 
       left="1.7cm">
              <fo:inline>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(concat('nato a ', OnoriLuogoNas, ' il ', 
     bornDate))"/>
              </fo:inline>
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block text-align="left" margin-top="0.98cm" font-family="Times New Roman" margin- 
       left="1.7cm">
              <fo:inline font-style="Times New Roman" font-size="14pt">
                ~ ~~~~~~~~ ~~
              </fo:inline>
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block text-align="center" font-size="19pt" font-family="Times New Roman" margin- 
         top="0.96cm">
                ~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block text-align="center" font-size="19pt" font-family="Times New Roman" margin- 
         top="0.45cm">
                ~~~~~~~~~
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block text-align="center" font-size="19pt" font-family="Times New Roman" margin- 
              top="0.4cm">
              <fo:inline>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(concat('DI ', translate(OnoriTipOnor, 
       $lowercase, $uppercase)))"/>
              </fo:inline>
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block text-align="left" font-size="12pt" font-family="Times New Roman" margin- 
      top="1.19cm" margin-left="1.7cm">
                ~~ ~~~
            </fo:block>
            <fo:list-block provisional-label-separation="20pt" margin-left="1.8cm" margin- 
     top="1.16cm">
              <fo:list-item>
                <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
                  <fo:block font-size="14pt" font-family="italic">
                    <fo:inline font-style="italic">
                      ~~~~,
                    </fo:inline>
                  </fo:block>
                </fo:list-item-label>
                <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">
                  <fo:block font-family="Times New Roman" font-size="14pt" margin-left="0.5cm">
                    <fo:inline font-family="Times New Roman">
                      <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(concat(' ', currentDate))"/> 
                    </fo:inline>
                  </fo:block>
                </fo:list-item-body>
              </fo:list-item>
            </fo:list-block>
            <fo:block text-align="center" font-size="13pt" font-family="Times New Roman" margin- 
         top="0.76cm" margin-left="7.58cm">
              <fo:inline>
                IL CAPO REPARTO
              </fo:inline>
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block text-align="center" font-size="13pt" font-family="Times New Roman" margin- 
      left="7.58cm">
              <fo:inline>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(concat('Dirig. Dott.', '~~~~~~ ~~~~~~'))"/>
              </fo:inline>
            </fo:block>


    <!-- </fo:block-container>  -->
        </fo:flow>
      </fo:page-sequence>
    </xsl:for-each> 

 </fo:root>
 </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="italic">
   <fo:inline font-weight="italic">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
   </fo:inline>
   </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify a background image on `fo:region-body`.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_region-body, where "7.8 Common Border, Padding, and Background Properties" (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#common-border-padding-and-background-properties) includes `background-image` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#background-image).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i'll check immediately, though I have a question, does the fop version matter for the background?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know.  I usually only use AH Formatter.

Comment: Don't worry. At the end I used a newer version of FOP (and its libraries) and followed your suggestion. Thanks a lot, have a good day.